# Unique unchangeable id for core data object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

i'm making a small playlist app at the moment.

i've made a playlistName entity which contain the name of the playlist.

then i've made a song entity which contains all the songs in all the playlists. To know which song is in which playlist i've stored the ObjectID from the selected playlist object in an attribute called selectedRow.

This is how i would do it in other language like PHP/SQL. The problem is here, that every time i run the app the playlists objectID seem to change. So the saved objectID in the song entity wont be the same as the playlist objectID when the app is restarted.

How should i approach this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, instead of doing this manually by storing objectIDs, you'd set up a many-to-many relationship from playlist to song. One of Core Data's primary features is its ability to manage relationships between objects in an object graph.

Assuming you're going to do it the way you've described, you should know that the `NSManagedObjectID` you get from `-objectID` will change when an object's managed object context is first saved after insertion of the object. After that, it will be constant, even between launches of the app.

Again though, it doesn't sound like you really need to store objectIDs to do what you're describing.

Comment: Well i do not know if my way is the right approach. if you have an better approach, i would like to hear it :)

Comment: I described the approach I'd recommend in the first paragraph of my answer. Use [relationships](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdRelationships.html) :)

Comment: Okay i'll take a look at the many-to-many relationships. cheers